# Gravity and Newton's 2nd law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction

I started to wonder what would be different when opening e.g. a very heavy door (e.g.m=10 tons) of a safe here on Earth and on the Moon. Lifting (!) the door (taken of its hinges) straight up here on Earth requires more force than on the Moon.

But what about when we close the door (on the hinges). The force we create to move the door is perpendicular to the gravitational acceleration. Does closing the door on the Moon require the same force as on Earth?

Comment: Yes, it does, for the reason you describe.

Comment: Almost. Friction will probably be higher on Earth because the weight of the door will cause more torque on the hinges. But, I think that very heavy doors are usually, at least partially, balanced, so that the axis is not very far away from the center of gravity.

Comment: @rodrigo Good point.

Comment: A more descriptive title would be "Horizontal rotations and torque in different gravitational fields."

Comment: Further to rodrigo's comment, dry friction is approximately proportional to normal force (which would just be weight on a flat surface) in the Coulomb model, so depends on local gravity.

Answer (score 3):

If you assume the hinge on the door is perfectly stable and frictionless, and you don't have to 'lift' the door against gravity, you are really left with a question of rotational inertia which is not dependent on gravity. So, the force required to shut the door will not change based on the gravity field the door is in.